# MPMoviePlayerViewController done button not working

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a place where I allow users to select a video from a UIImagePicker that is then played via an MPMoviePlayerViewController. This works fine, except when the Done button is pressed it just pauses the video and doesn't dismiss it from full screen. I've been led to believe that the default behavior of the done button is to dismiss the video, so I'm not really sure what's stopping it from doing that, or what I can change to make it happen. Here's my current code, I've tried a few alterations that I'll make a note of after the code.

```
NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef) mediaType,  kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
{
    videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
}

moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[moviePlayer.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                              object:nil];

[moviePlayer.moviePlayer stop];
[moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I've tried changing `[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];` to `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:];` but that just doesn't do anything. I've put a couple different variations of this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];
```

with the rest of the initialization code but that hasn't helped either.

Edit: If the video is allowed to keep playing until the end it doesn't dismiss either, it's just stuck with the video player in fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the observer, the object parameter should be moviePlayer.moviePlayer and not just moviePlayer.

The moviePlayer.moviePlayer (class MPMoviePlayerController) is the one sending the notification, not the moviePlayer (class MPMoviePlayerViewController).

So change this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
       name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
```

to this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
       name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification moviePlayer.moviePlayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3, this worked for me:

```
//register the observer
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CameraSetupViewController.moviePlayerDoneButtonClicked), name: NSNotification.Name.MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish, object: nil)

        moviePlayerPlay()
}

//moviePlayer play function
func moviePlayerPlay() {
     let url:NSURL = NSURL( string: "https://tendinsights.com/Video.mp4" )

     if let movieViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController( contentURL: url as URL! ) 
           self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(movieViewController)
                movieViewController.moviePlayer.play()       
     }
}

//moviePlayer Done Button Pressed
func moviePlayerDoneButtonClicked(_ notification: NSNotification) {        
    let reason = notification.userInfo?[MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey]

    if (MPMovieFinishReason(rawValue: reason as! Int) == MPMovieFinishReason.userExited) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```